# Recognize pattern matches in String with regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string, expression

In short, the system I am working on has many layers. In Java, I will get a String containing a condition to evaluate. I will be receiving a string with possible occurrences of function calls to a function called "days(int)". The string may look like:

```
1405555200 + days(4)
```

or

```
1405555200 + days(param_date)
```

where the first operands are Unix timestamps. Dates in the system are converted to Unix time (Long). Essentially, this days(x) thing inside the string is just a notation for "add this many days to the timestamp". Since one day is 86400 seconds, we can simplify this notation to "add 86400 times the parameter to the other operand".

I need to find all occurences of this pattern and turn

```
1405555200 + days(param_date)
```

into

```
1405555200 + (86400 * param_date)
```

How can I do this cleanly?

Comment: Do you want to do same for `1405555200 + days(4)` as well?

Comment: @Braj, yes, the code does not actually have to do the arithmetic of the multiplication. It just has to replace the text. The parameter that the days function gets could be a literal int value, or a reference to be looked up later.

Comment: but the answers do it for all. Let me update my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
String newString = oldString.replaceAll("days\\(([^)]+)\\)", "(86400 * $1)");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I am bad with regex. The parameter "days\\((\\d+)\\)" was what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> The code does not actually have to do the arithmetic of the multiplication.It just has to replace the text.

This should work with substitution.

```
(\d+ \+ )days\(([A-Za-z_]+)\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/18)

Sample code:

```
String str="1405555200 + days(param_date)";
String regex="(\\d+ \\+ )days\\(([A-Za-z_]+)\\)";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(regex, "$1(86400 * $2)"));
```

output:

```
1405555200 + (86400 * param_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

To be safe if the text between the parentheses could be anything,  I would use:

```
String s = "1405555200 + days(4)";
String r = s.replaceAll("days\\((.*?)\\)", "(86400 * $1)");
System.out.println(r); //=> "1405555200 + (86400 * 4)"
```